# What is the difference between PowerShell and cmd.exe command syntax?

Tags: powershell, cmd, winrm

I am running the following command in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\adminaccount> winrm s winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true";
MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="4294967295"}
Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
```

Which gives me an error, as you could see. But the same command in cmd.exe works fine:

```
C:\Users\adminaccount>winrm s winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true";
MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="4294967295"}
Service
...
```

So, what should I know about PowerShell syntax to get this working there?

Comment: Shouldn't `"` be quoted (e.g. by \`)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't know, I have last touched PowerShell of the version 3, and never worked with it any more. But why do you think that `"` should be quoted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@{}` defines a hashtable in PowerShell, but `winrm` expects a string argument. Put that argument in quotes if you want to run the command directly in PowerShell:

```
winrm s winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"; MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="4294967295"}'
```

Also, you need admin privileges for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the special `--%` parameter which lets PowerShell stop parsing the parameters.

```
winrm --% s winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true";MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser="4294967295"}
```

Comment: This works, but not if there a PowerShell in there that should be expanded. Example: ` + $redirectSpec` at the end and `$redirectSpec` containing "`>> _output_2018-09-07T195607.txt`".

Answer (score 1):

You can prefix your command with cmd /c and quote it like:

```
cmd /c "winrm s winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted=`"true`";
MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser=`"4294967295`"}"
```

PowerShell will execute executables that exist in the system.

Comment: Still not working: "Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help."

Comment: Well, I was trying to explain the difference as you asked. You will need to take care of special chars, escape quotes etc. See updated command

Comment: Depending on the command, you might need to start the Powershell in Admin mode...